# Как указать кавычку в @"" строке

Tags: c#, minecraft

**В общем, пишу лаунчер Minecraft для личных целей на C#** **Имеется такая строка запуска**
`java -Djava.library.path=./libraries/natives/ -cp "./libraries/*" net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username %username% --version 1.16.5 --gameDir . --assetsDir ./assets --assetIndex 1.16 --uuid %uuid% --accessToken %accessToken% --userType mojang --versionType testver`

**Visual Studio сильно ругается на** `-cp "./libraries/*"` **менял строки на свои что-бы vs не ругался, майн не запускается**
*Библиотеки просьба не предлагать!*

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"java -Djava.library.path=./libraries/natives/ -cp "./ libraries/*" net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username %username% --version 1.16.5 --gameDir . --assetsDir ./assets --assetIndex 1.16 --uuid %uuid% --accessToken %accessToken% --userType mojang --versionType testver";
```

код: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а приведите код лаунчера? Ну, той части, где определяются строки? может, вы не написали что то типа string s = @"java -Djava.library.path=./libraries/natives/ -cp /"./libraries/*/""

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/verbatim

Чтобы привести в буквальной `@` строке кавычку как символ, а не признак конца строки, надо ее удвоить `""` вместо `"`.

```cs
p.StartInfo.Arguments = @"java -Djava.library.path=./libraries/natives/ -cp ""./ libraries/*"" net.minecraft.client.main.Main --username %username% --version 1.16.5 --gameDir . --assetsDir ./assets --assetIndex 1.16 --uuid %uuid% --accessToken %accessToken% --userType mojang --versionType testver";
```